# Tx stuck even after using gasestimation for gas limit

Tags: gas-limit, gas-price, gas-estimate, ethereumjs-tx

I am trying to sign a manual transaction using ethereumjs-tx to interact with a smart contract.

This is how I am getting my gaslimit, nounce and data for the params

```
 var GAS = await cont.methods.withdraw("100000000000000000").estimateGas({from: address}, 
 function(error, estimatedGas) {
      console.log(estimatedGas);
    });
    console.log("gas limit is"+GAS);

    var nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address);
    console.log(nonce);

    var hexData = await cont.methods.withdraw("100000000000000000").encodeABI();
    console.log(hexData);
```

And this is how I am declaring the params for ethTx object :

```
  const params = {
            nonce: nonce,
            to: contractAddress, //address of the receiver
            value: '0x000', // value in hexa format
            gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex('100'),
            gasLimit: GAS,
            chainId: 42, // 1 for main ethereum chain
            data: hexData
          };
```

This is the txHash for the code after running the script [txhash](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x50875ff2727f0a59982baaf6c7999ca03dfa5425d31d51d3192a759a6d244a73).

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help me get into the right path. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even tho it shouldn't matter because it's a test net, they may not like such a low gas price of 0.0000001 Gwei. Try to replace the transaction by sending a higher gas price, maybe at least 1 Gwei

Comment: So doesn't web3.utils.toHex('100') means 100 Gwei??

Comment: It means 100 wei, which is 0.0000001 Gwei, which is 0.0000000000000001 ETH. You can convert them here: https://eth-converter.com/